# Error calling Javascript in Camping App

Tags: javascript, ruby, camping

I want to learn about webapps. I decided to learn by doing and chose to start simple with Camping as (i). it is small & (ii). i know some ruby.

I think I am comfortable with the HTML and CSS side of things and using MAB. So i decided to step up and add some javascript which fails to work. Here is the offending code snippet from my View:

```
    div.image do
      link :rel => 'stylesheet', :href => 'styles.css'
      script :type =>"text/javascript", :src => 'display_date.js'
      # The hash argument always go at the end.
      button 'Display Date', :type => "button", :onclick => "displayDate" 
    end
```

The javascript file looks like this:

```
function displayDate()
{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
```

When I click the 'Display Date' button on the screen Firefox webconsole reports

> -- [18:32:46.762] ReferenceError: displayDate is not defined

It does not work on IE either. The camping file and the Javascript file are in the same directory. Please advise. The result I get is however better than adding the Javascript inline which results in a stack error, I can live without inline js but it would be handy to know how to code this also.

Comment: Look at the generated source.

Comment: Dont understand you. Please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to camping and Ruby too, so this may be horrible. It works though ;)

Give the controllers module a route to serve display_date.js to the client:

```
class MyJS < R '/display_date\.js'    
  JS = File.read('display_date.js')
  def get
    @headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8'
    JS
  end
end
```

Call displayDate as a function, with parens: `:onclick => displayDate()`.

Comment: The proper solution here is to place the file under the `public` folder (like `public/display_date.js`. As long as you use the Camping Server (`camping myapp.rb`) it should be served correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To get the function to be called you must put in `onclick = "javascript:displayData()"`

Comment: Thanx for the input. Changed the line to become: 
button 'Display Date', :type => "button", :onclick => "javascript:displayData()" 
but it still failed.

Comment: Is your code this <button type = button onclick= "javascript:displayData()"> Display Date </button>

Comment: The HTML source becomes this <script type="text/javascript" src="display_date.js"></script><button type="button" onclick="javascript:displayData()">Display Date</button>

Comment: Do you have the <body> tag and <head> tag

Comment: Here is the first bit. THANKS! <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Custom Made Kameez</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css" media="screen"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" media="screen"></head><body id="content">...

Comment: And the error is still "displayDate is not defined" are you sure the functions name is displayDate and the onclick says displayData

Comment: Looking further into the issue I also noticed the following error when i shut down the server and then restart: display_date.js "[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  172ms]" so it seems the js file itself cannot be found. Am I referencing the fie location correctly? I am aware of another thread where a user could not find the db file. The solution was that it is always put in the home directory. Placing my js file there does not fix this.

Comment: What I think your error means (The first one) is that the function displayDate cannot be found, it happen if you write the onclick wrong. Or if the function is written wrong. In ever function it needs to be something like this function displayDate() { your code in here}. Is every thing written correctly in your function. Or if the link to the js file is written incorrect.